# Why won't Mail sync To Do/Tasks with Exchange?

Tags: macos, exchange, apple-mail

I'm using Apple Mail (Snow Leopard, everything is fully up-to-date), and am happily using an Exchange 2007 server for email needs, but I can't get it to synchronise the To Do notes from Mail with the Tasks from Exchange. I've tried creating a task in each and neither of them went to the other side.

Bizarrely I have a single task from before I actually upgraded to Snow Leopard that did get into Mail from Exchange.

Right-clicking on the Inbox and hitting 'Get Account Info' in Mail reports the correct number of entries in the 'To Do' folder for 'Messages on Server'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the To Do notes are synchronised through iCal (which I tend to only open when I specifically require it), and ***not*** through Mail itself.

With iCal doing its automatic refresh, and the ability to force the tasks to manually refresh the problem is solved.